# Do we study graphs whose vertices are the edges of another graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Consider the following method of creating a graph $G'(V',E')$ from a graph $G(V,E)$:

An edge of G becomes a vertex of G'
Two verteces $v', w'\in V'$ are connected if the edges they come from are connected. That is, if $e_1,e_2\in E$ are such that $\exists u,v,w\in V\ :\ e_1=(u,v), e_2=(v,w)$

That way an isolated cycle stays the same kind of cycle. An isolated edge becomes an isolated vertex.

It's always possible to do this forward but its not always possible to find the "inverse" of a graph.

If we keep finding the correspondant G', G''etc it can either stabilize, disapear or diverge into an infinitely big graph.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph

Comment: This is called the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of the original graph.  "Is it studied?"  Yes.

Comment: In particular, see the [section on iterating the line graph operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Iterating_the_line_graph_operator).